# select specific tr and specific td within selected tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been able to select the specific rows that I wanted but I can't select specific td from those tr.

I used this to select rows:

```
$('#time-slot tr:not(:first, :last)')
```

then within those selected rows I was trying to ignore the first and the last td but it is not working. I used similar approach as above

```
$('#time-slot tr:not(:first, :last) td:not(:first, :last)')
```

Any ideas how should I approach this problem. Btw I am trying to click and drag the mouse to paint the cells with user defined color.

Comment: could u show me ur table structure?

Comment: Try using `not` and `filter` methods.

Comment: Don't understand your issue. Your code seems working i tested it. What is exactly your question?

Comment: @sachleen your code is not working, it is not ignoring the first and second row and not ignoring the first and second cell

Comment: added a fiddle below which shows your code is working.

Comment: @Jai I see it's working on jsfiddle but I tested the code on my application, it does not work. It does not ignore the first and last cells.

Comment: @Jai http://jsfiddle.net/BEp5W/1/ Yours "worked" because you used **3** rows and **3** columns. Increase them and it won't work. It was a lucky number that I knew would produce incorrect results, that's why I used 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using less of a string selector and more of the jQuery methods, as well as using the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors for your problem:

```
$("#time-slot").find("tr").not(":first-child, :last-child").find("td").not(":first-child, :last-child").addClass("active");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7b4Ms/

Depending on what you are expecting, which you haven't explained very well, this may or may not be what you want. What this does is select all `tr` elements that are not the first and last. Inside of those matched `tr` elements, it selects all `td` elements that are not first and last. So basically, it doesn't select the outside ring of cells in the `table`.

Comment: @Jai It's working fine? Then why did they ask a question? They said they can't select the specific `td` elements they want. This is my interpretation of what they expect. It may **work**, but it doesn't seem to work _correctly_ in their opinion, hence their question.

Comment: thats fine but code is working and should be asked the issue?

Comment: @Jai my code was only ignoring first and last row but it was not ignoring the first and second cells of the selected rows. However Ian's code is completely working and exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Ian, just I prefer to use .children() instead of .find(). Because it can make a problem if you have nested tables.

```
$("#time-slot").find("tr").not(":first-child, :last-child").find("td").not(":first-child, :last-child").addClass("active");
```

changes to:

```
$("#time-slot").children("tr").not(":first-child, :last-child").children("td").not(":first-child, :last-child").addClass("active");
```

Comment: what kind of problem are you talking about?

Comment: I definitely agree, but maybe the selection of nested stuff is desired. The original selector used was `#time-slot tr:not(:first, :last)` (meaning find all descendents...same as `.find()`), not `#time-slot > tr:not(:first, :last)` (meaning find all children...same as `.children()`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (uses css selectors only):

```
$("#time-slot tr:not(:first,:last) td:not(:first-child,:last-child)").addClass("active");
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pw5M8/)**